# applying django forms to html template

Tags: html, django, forms

i got a alrdy done html template , i'm trying to add register form to this template, idk hot to insert form fields. i tried to add {{ form.'fieldname' }} to input , but it doesn't effect.
can't find any docs , sorry for silly question

```
<section class="signup">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="signup-content">
                    <div class="signup-form">
                        <h2 class="form-title">Sign up</h2>
                        <form method="POST" class="register-form" id="register-form" action="">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="re-pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                                <input type="password" name="re_pass" id="re_pass"
                                       placeholder="Repeat your password"/>
                            </div>
                           
                            <div class="form-group form-button">
                                <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit"
                                       value="Register"/>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

*forms*

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=255)
    password1 = forms.PasswordInput()
    password2 = forms.PasswordInput()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

*views*

```
class RegisterFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = '/login/'
    template_name = 'blog/signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()

        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(RegisterFormView, self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()

        return context
```

Comment: you do not set the field name in '', just render it with `{{ form.fieldname }}`

Comment: @Jonas at <input name=''> ? am i right?

Comment: please post both your forms.py and views.py

Comment: @Jonas added forms and views

Comment: if you return your form as `form` within context you can use `{{ form.name }}` to render the name field of the form in a div e.g.